# Typescript thinks that a variable is `possibly undefined` even when I specifically tested it to not be undefined before using it

Tags: typescript, lodash, conditional-operator, react-typescript

I have a ternary operator checking for a few condition which is something like this:

```
 !_.isUndefined(count) && count < 10 ? 12: count < 100 ? 28: 44
```

typescripts gives an error here saying `count is possibly 'undefined'`

This condition works fine if I remove one of the count conditions like:

```
!_.isUndefined(count) && count < 10 ? 12: 44
```

Is there a way to get rid of this error ?

Comment: Is this a lodash-specific question?  If so then maybe you should tag it as such; if not, could you make sure your code is a [mre] without third-party dependencies? (Either way, you should probably define `count` so that we can paste your code into a standalone IDE and demonstrate the issue for ourselves.)

Answer (score 1):

If count is undefined, this condition is false:

```
!_.isUndefined(count) && count
```

therefore the second condition will be evaluated:

```
count < 100
```

but this would use count even though it might be undefined. The warning seems logical and justified.

In your second case, there is no second condition, so no problem.

Maybe you meant to do this?

```
 !_.isUndefined(count) && (count < 10 ? 12: count < 100 ? 28: 44)
```

or this?

```
count == undefined ? 0 : count < 10 ? 12: count < 100 ? 28: 44
```